# Resolving power of a diffraction grating

Tags: diffraction, spectroscopy

For a experiment we have measured the wavelengths of the spectrallines corresponding to a sodium lamp. We have also measured the splitting distance, most likely to happen due to spin-orbit coupling, of a specific spectralline. Accordingly we have calculated the differences in the wavelengths of those splitted spectrallines. Now I was wondering why you are able to calculate the resolving power of the diffraction grating based on these wavelength difference. Is this because the splitting is typically very small and is therefore sensitive to the ability of the diffraction grating to separate closely spaced spectral lines? They do not seem to be anywhere near resolved.

[image]

Comment: @EdV Nice results you have! I have estimated the seperation in pixels, but I am not able to determine the FWHM. What I am able to approximate is the wavelength of one of the splitted spectral lines. It might seem too obvious, but isn't the resolving power of the diffraction grating then given by $R = m \cdot \frac{\lambda}{\Delta \lambda}$?

Comment: @EdV Understandable, they are closely related. We used a reflective diffraction grating with 600 lines per mm. The camera we used had a pixel width of 3,6 micrometer. In case you think you need it.

Comment: @EdV How am I able to reduce the effects of the triangular monochromator bandpasses next time? By using multiple gratings or filters, or both? I am also not able to find the results in the chemistry meta link.

Comment: Based on the answer given by Farcher, and the HyperPhysics link therein, I see that resolving power is different that resolvance. The former depends on spectral line width(s) while the latter depends on line center separation. So the sodium D lines have a resolvance around 1000, but a high resolution spectrograph can have much higher resolving power for those lines, etc. Interesting.

Comment: As per the second paragraph in the answer by @ProfRob here: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/49359/45954, **resolving power** is not the same as **resolution** and neither are the same as **resolvance**. The HyperPhysics link in Farcher’s answer discusses the latter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your image shows are two fringes produced by light approximate wavelengths $589.0\,\rm nm$ and $589.6\,\rm nm$ which is a difference of $0.6\,\rm nm$.

Those two images are quite clearly resolved as shown below at the left-hand side.

[image]

I have "moved" the two fringes closer together to show that the fringes could be even closer together and still be resolved.

Analysis of the image on a pixel scale suggests that the [resolving power of the diffraction grating](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/phyopt/gratres.html), $\lambda/\Delta \lambda$ with $\Delta \lambda \approx 0.13\,\rm nm$ is approximately 4500 and most probably an underestimate.
The closeness of the fringes means that assumption used to find the separation of the fringes, that the displacement in pixels is proportional to the difference wavelength, is a reasonable one.

Theory tells one that the resolving power is equal to $mN$ where $m$ is the order of the fringes and $N$ is the total number of slits illuminated.
Thus measurement of the diameter of the collimator/telescope lens and knowledge of the order of the fringes should enable one get an order of magnitude estimate the number of lines per mm on the diffraction grating.

Comment: Clear explenation! How did you calculate the wavelength difference without knowing the pixel width? Or did you use the pixel width that I mentioned?

Comment: I used a drawing package with the pointer set to measure a position on the image in pixels, eg (x,y) = (345,234).  The scaling was done by measuring the separation, in pixels,  between the corresponding edges of the two fringes and knowing the difference in wavelength between the two spectral lines. The yellow lines that I have drawn on your image have a width of one pixel.